# Laravel Vapor {“message”:“The security token included in the request is invalid.”}

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-vapor

I successfully deployed an app on AWS with Laravel Vapor.

```
  ==> Ensuring Storage Exists
  ==> Ensuring Cache Table Is Configured
  ==> Updating Function Configurations
  ==> Updating Function Code
  ==> Running Deployment Hooks
  ==> Ensuring Rest API Is Configured
  ==> Ensuring Custom Domains Exist
  ==> Ensuring DNS Records Exist
  ==> Ensuring Mail Is Configured
  ==> Ensuring Scheduled Tasks Are Configured
  ==> Ensuring Queues Are Configured
  ==> Updating Function Aliases To New Version

  Project deployed successfully. (1m26s)

=============== =================================================== 
  Deployment ID   Environment URL (Copied To Clipboard)              
 =============== =================================================== 
  38261           https://clean-kyiv-40wzwvz1sutk.vapor-farm-a1.com  
 =============== ===================================================
```

However, when I go on the given link `https://clean-kyiv-40wzwvz1sutk.vapor-farm-a1.com` I am getting 502 Error
[image: 502]

After requesting the link I can see, on Vapor, in the `Log` tab inside the staging environment next message.

[image: a busy cat]

What else should I check to resolve that issue?

Comment: Why are you pointing CloudFlare at a Vapor app, which already has CloudFront in place?

Comment: I have not done something custom here. All the steps I took from Vapor documentation. If you think it is something I should check can you point me at the right place?

Comment: Interesting. Looks like custom domains on Vapor go through CloudFront, but the default vapor-farm-a1.com ones go through CloudFlare. Weird; ignore me, in that case.

Comment: The sandbox domains all go through Cloudflare since that's how Taylor set this thing up to generate the random wildcard domains. I found I would get some 502 errors when my HTML had some special characters in it, like curly single quotes instead of plain (') apostrophes. I think it must have to do with Cloudflares WAF firewall protection. Removing all special characters from the HTTP response usually fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Hi, getting the same error. Did you manage to fix that?
It has nothing with Cloudflare, I don't use Cloudflare and still getting this error

Comment: I think you get these errors only for the first build while everything is getting set up. It went away for me after an hour or so. I put it down to DNS propagation :)

Comment: @BobB I am facing similar issue and I am only getting the below details in the log
"2023-09-21T11:46:36.063Z 8c113dcf-2ae9-476c-9503-456bc2e1cd86 Task timed out after 10.01 seconds" .
I changed the timeout to 5mins and checked the same issue is happeing.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing your deployment timeout if for some reason your code runs for longer than the default 10sec you will get this error from aws Lambda

```
    environments:
        production:
            memory: 1024
            cli-memory: 512
            timeout: 120
```

[image]

Comment: I am facing the same issue, and waited for 1 day and still the same issue is happening